# Handle scroll up event for button on focus of Text-Input in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native.
In my case, when my Text-Input is focused Keyboard pop-up and which hides my view in which button is present.

My code snippet :

```
 <KeyboardAvoid>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row',width:dwidth-20,marginHorizontal:20,marginTop:15}}>
            <TextInput 
            style={{width:width-60,fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18,}}
            placeholder={this.state.quesText}
            autoCapitalize="words"
            onKeyPress={this.typing}
            value={this.state.questionText}
            onChangeText={ (questionText) => this.setState({questionText})}
            />
          </View>
          </KeyboardAvoid>
        </View>

        <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 0.5,paddingVertical:1,borderBottomColor: '#fff',}}/>

        <View style ={{flexDirection:'row',height:dheight/15,backgroundColor:'#fff',paddingLeft:18}}>
          <CheckBox style={{padding:5,marginBottom:2}} onClick={ () => this.setState({ showUserImg: !this.state.showUserImg,textValue: !this.state.textValue,anonymFlage:"Y"}) } checkBoxColor="#2b73e1"/>
          <Text style={{marginTop:6,fontSize:16,marginLeft:5,}}>
          {this.state.askAnonText}
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={(e) => this.formValidation()}>
             <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{Post}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
```

I don't want to hide my button "Post" when keyboard appears. How can i moveup my Post button when keyboard appears, on click on textinput. What's the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution, and the easiest to install, is [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html). It’s a core component but it’s also pretty simple in what it does. This will make your views flow more naturally with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
.
.
.

<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',width:dwidth-20,marginHorizontal:20,marginTop:15}}>
      <TextInput  style={{width:width-60,fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:18,}}
                  placeholder={this.state.quesText}
                  autoCapitalize="words"
                  onKeyPress={this.typing}
                  value={this.state.questionText}
                  onChangeText={ (questionText) => this.setState({questionText})}
      />
    </View>
    <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 0.5,paddingVertical:1,borderBottomColor: '#fff',}}>
      <View style ={{flexDirection:'row',height:dheight/15,backgroundColor:'#fff',paddingLeft:18}}>
        <CheckBox style={{padding:5,marginBottom:2}}
                  onClick={ () => this.setState({ showUserImg:!this.state.showUserImg,textValue:!this.state.textValue,anonymFlage:"Y"})}
                  checkBoxColor="#2b73e1"/>
        <Text style={{marginTop:6,fontSize:16,marginLeft:5,}}>
          {this.state.askAnonText}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={(e) => this.formValidation()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{Post}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>

.
.
.
.
```

before navigate to other screen just dismissKeyboard by calling the dismissKeyboard() method from

```
import dismissKeyboard from 'dismissKeyboard';
```

(this package)

Comment: @badugabiz it works for both android and ios.. if it did't work just let me know.

Comment: hi @badugabiz is it working for you in android and ios?